# NiFi ExecuteSqlRecord not processing SQL query(Presto)

Tags: mysql, apache, apache-nifi, presto

I am running a simple Pivot query in Presto via "ExecuteSqlRecord" processor but the moment I run the processor it gives me the error: **Unable to execute SQL select**.

Query is:

```
with map_date as 
(
 SELECT 
 vin, 
 epoch,
 timestamp,
 date,
 map_agg(signalName, value) as map_values
from hive.vehicle_signals.vehicle_signals_flat
 where date(date) = date('2020-02-28') 
 and vin = '000015'
 and signalName in ('timestamp','epoch','msgId','usec','vlan','vin','msgName','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H',
 'J','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U','V','W','X',
 'Y','Z','A1','A5','A2','A3','A4','A6','A8','A9','A10','A11','A12')
 GROUP BY vin, epoch, timestamp, date
order by timestamp asc 
)
SELECT
  epoch
, timestamp
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A'] ELSE NULL END AS A
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'B') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['B'] ELSE NULL END AS B
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'C') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['C'] ELSE NULL END AS C
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'D') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['D'] ELSE NULL END AS D
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'E') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['E'] ELSE NULL END AS E
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'F') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['F'] ELSE NULL END AS F
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'G') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['G'] ELSE NULL END AS G
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'H') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['H'] ELSE NULL END AS H
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'J') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['J'] ELSE NULL END AS J
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'K') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['K'] ELSE NULL END AS K
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'L') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['L'] ELSE NULL END AS L
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'M') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['M'] ELSE NULL END AS M
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'N') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['N'] ELSE NULL END AS N
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'O') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['O'] ELSE NULL END AS O
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'P') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['P'] ELSE NULL END AS P
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'R') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['R'] ELSE NULL END AS R
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'S') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['S'] ELSE NULL END AS S
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'T') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['T'] ELSE NULL END AS T
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'U') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['U'] ELSE NULL END AS U
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'V') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['V'] ELSE NULL END AS V
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'W') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['W'] ELSE NULL END AS W
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'X') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['X'] ELSE NULL END AS X
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'Y') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['Y'] ELSE NULL END AS Y
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'Z') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['Z'] ELSE NULL END AS Z
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A1') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A1'] ELSE NULL END AS A1
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A2') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A2'] ELSE NULL END AS A2
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A3') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A3'] ELSE NULL END AS A3
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A4') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A4'] ELSE NULL END AS A4
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A5') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A5'] ELSE NULL END AS A5
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A6') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A6'] ELSE NULL END AS A6
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A8') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A8'] ELSE NULL END AS A8
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A9') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A9'] ELSE NULL END AS A9
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A10') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A10'] ELSE NULL END AS A10
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A11') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A11'] ELSE NULL END AS A11
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'A12') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['A12'] ELSE NULL END AS A12
, vin
, date
from map_date
```

I can run the ABOVE query in ExecuteSqlRecord perfectly fine if I pivot only ~20 fields but when pivoting ~37 fields then the ExecuteSqlRecord processor immediately Fails.

It is interesting to see that I  can run the same pivot query with ~37 fields in Presto CLI and QueryDatabaseTable successfully! Please help me achieve this in ExecuteSQLRecord processor as it has the added benefit of writing the output flowfile in any desired format (for my case, I am writing the output of the SQL query as CSV)

Here is the full stack trace of the error,

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query. No FlowFile to route to failure: java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query

java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:279)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:228)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoPreparedStatement.<init>(PrestoPreparedStatement.java:80)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoConnection.prepareStatement(PrestoConnection.java:129)

 at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:303)

 at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:303)

 at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractExecuteSQL.onTrigger(AbstractExecuteSQL.java:237)

 at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)

 at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)

 at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error fetching next at http://presto.testk8s.content.mywebspace.com:8889/b7/journal/20245300229_0354554_08r940_as8y4/2?slug=78234778257265 returned an invalid response: JsonResponse{statusCode=500, statusMessage=Server Error, headers={connection=[close]}, hasValue=false} [Error: ]

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClientV1.requestFailedException(StatementClientV1.java:446)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.internal.client.StatementClientV1.advance(StatementClientV1.java:386)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.getColumns(PrestoResultSet.java:1742)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoResultSet.<init>(PrestoResultSet.java:119)

 at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:250)

 ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It seems executesql begins processing only if a few select cases are found in the sql query but not if it's more than a few. Can anyone from the nifi community comment on this behavior?

Comment: query is too long. Presto jdbc statement can carry only 4k text yet, or you should set the header size to increase in your server setting for Presto 3xx but I am not sure for 2xx versions.

Comment: But as mentioned, the writer of this post is able to execute the same query via QueryDatabase and Presto CLI! So this seems more like an ExecuteSQLRecord issue.